# Deal with different type properties in a Union type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm working with the following code:

```
type PromiseOrValue<T> = Promise<T> | T;

function isPromise(value) {
  return Boolean(value && typeof value.then === 'function');
}

/**
 * Similar to Array.prototype.reduce(), however the reducing callback may return
 * a Promise, in which case reduction will continue after each promise resolves.
 *
 * If the callback does not return a Promise, then this function will also not
 * return a Promise.
 */
export default function promiseReduce<T, U>(
  values: ReadonlyArray<T>,
  callback: (arg0: U, arg1: T) => PromiseOrValue<U>,
  initialValue: PromiseOrValue<U>,
): PromiseOrValue<U> {
  return values.reduce(
    (previous, value) =>
      isPromise(previous)
        ? previous.then(resolved => callback(resolved, value))
        : callback(previous, value),
    initialValue,
  );
}
```

Typescript is complaining that `error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'PromiseOrValue<U>'`. Presumably because if `previous` is not a promise, there will be no `then` function property. Is there a way around this? (other than simply ignoring that line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `isPromise` function as a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) and typescript will be able to narrow the type of `previous` variable to `Promise`:

```
function isPromise(value: any): value is Promise<any> {
  return Boolean(value && typeof value.then === 'function');
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewLYEsDOEDycBqBDAGwFcIAeAFQD4oBeWRVDC6gHynIG4AoLgMyIB2AY2AoEAqOnjJ0EABQA3QiQBcUPAJABKNUuLR09GUw0hqAby5QocCMCJwJAIQQICEDYuXQAZD6igkAi8UHokAHTAABYQEjTxUADk-MKi4ola3AC+PAD0AFT5VvlQAMooqAR4cAEIUACCcHB4IOFgiMAIgRDhtgAmRELyWgA0UFEIAO4QChA10dD9gygCAOZQQoQEAEZ4QgDWUEgtNnYOAsXqRowQYytQk1EoQlEbeBinAyJiEpMoBAQNuJRAISOpeMA5lAPC8oO1jIsIGg3LM0OFipcAJIhBZvAG7A5QPoIJFQARdU72RxXaQ3MYLCTRQwpb7iB7-QGEZFkrqXWxUiR4a6ydFQfK5LgQAAeYAQcGARIgvDwRAICpZaQk8JuACUIF8yOQxgBVShyKyhbxoNR6vDEgQEECNZogZgjC2bfF7fZqOTVVYABjUxrG-oAjGpyFpaNRabJsPh9KRTe7rCsUKJCInVMKMAnvMnKO6dLmsLgC6aoJZrPzzpb9GilkNzdZrHJ2jMxEQ0GMwhBozRKBbW5I0HGMO3bAou2gtMOR1AAPxwqczyIxARyWzIgizPoxvE7b1bpEo-W97xaOcL1tqT1Hg6TzsIbsX-SjefpzMEbO3C2ZLgsiAA)

Comment: Thanks! I also tried using `as`:

`isPromise(previous)
        ? (previous as Promise<U>).then(resolved => callback(resolved, value))
        : callback(previous as U, value)`